# Can't remove any of the login options from 'My Logins'

Tags: bug, login, accounts

For some reason, I can't remove any of the login options in 'My Logins' in my account settings. All I get is an error message saying:

> Unable to remove login - please try again

I sent an email to the Stack Overflow support and I got referred to here (Stack Overflow Meta) for getting this resolved.

My current login options are:

- Stack Exchange
- Google
- Facebook
- Other (email address)

No matter which one I try to remove, I get the same error message — which by itself doesn't help much in telling me why the error is occurring.

Comment: The official support referred you to Meta?

Comment: You are clicking a remove link on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/9264447) , right?

Comment: @Stijn Yes, we've always sent bug reports to Meta. We only handle them through support if the bug is preventing the user from accessing the account (and thus they are incapable of posting on Meta).

Comment: @rene, yes exactly that page :)